# How to change which option is selected based on user's previous input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, session, input

Is there a way to change which `<option>` is selected based on what a user previously selected? I'm making a Flask app where users can input data into a form but if are not logged in, will need to log in and then be redirected back to the form. I want their previous input to be "stored" so they don't have to enter the info twice.

To store the information, I've used sessions and have tried something like `<input value = {{session.email}}>` This works for the `<input>` attribute but am wondering how to get the same effect with the `<select>` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have the selected option, something like `session.selectedOption`, you can set the attribute selected for the option you want

```html
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option selected>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I know I can used the selected element, but how do I have it change dynamically based on user's previous input?

Comment: You have the selectedOption in the session right ?
I think you can do something like this
<option {{ "selected" if session.selectedOption == "2"  else "" }}>2</option>
<option {{ "selected" if session.selectedOption == "3"  else "" }}>3</option>

Comment: Yup. That did it. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, you can set this answer as "Answer" so that it's considered done.